# League of Legends "Unhaled exception: error assertion failed in 32-bit code"

Tags: 14.04, wine, 32-bit, playonlinux

OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit, launching "League Of Legends" game through PlayonLinux
It worked nicely before last updates. I have problem after logging into client, it crashes each time almost immediately with following error code:

```
Unhandled exception: assertion failed in 32-bit code (0xf77fa440).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:f77fa440 ESP:1d5dbf54 EBP:1d5dd198 EFLAGS:00000296(   - --  I S -A-P- )
 EAX:00000000 EBX:0000130f ECX:000013e6 EDX:00000006
 ESI:7ddb0000 EDI:f75dc000
Stack dump:
0x1d5dbf54:  1d5dd198 00000006 000013e6 f7460607
0x1d5dbf64:  f75dc000 1d5dc004 f7463a33 00000006
0x1d5dbf74:  1d5dbf84 00000000 f74a8708 1d5dbfc0
0x1d5dbf84:  00000020 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x1d5dbf94:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x1d5dbfa4:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0xf77fa440 __kernel_vsyscall+0x10() in [vdso].so (0x1d5dd198)
  1 0xf7460607 gsignal+0x46() in libc.so.6 (0x1d5dd198)
  2 0xf7463a33 abort+0x142() in libc.so.6 (0x1d5dd198)
  3 0xf7459757 in libc.so.6 (+0x27756) (0x1d5dd198)
  4 0xf7459807 __assert_fail+0x56() in libc.so.6 (0x1d5dd198)
  5 0x7e17b37f in wininet (+0xb37e) (0x1d5dd198)
  6 0x7e17b3df in wininet (+0xb3de) (0x1d5dd1e8)
  7 0x7e19406c in wininet (+0x2406b) (0x1d5de328)
  8 0x7e197ba6 HttpSendRequestW+0x1f5() in wininet (0x1d5de398)
  9 0x7e197ce3 HttpSendRequestA+0xf2() in wininet (0x1d5de408)
  10 0x10345fa7 in adobe air (+0x345fa6) (0x1d5de90c)
  11 0x00000000 (0x1d5dea08)
  12 0x7bc80190 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x1d5dea18)
  13 0x7bc8309d call_thread_func+0x7c() in ntdll (0x1d5deae8)
  14 0x7bc8016e RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x1d5deb08)
  15 0x7bc8952c in ntdll (+0x7952b) (0x1d5df358)
  16 0xf75e6f70 start_thread+0xcf() in libpthread.so.0 (0x1d5df428)
  17 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  18 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  19 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  20 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  21 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  22 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  23 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  24 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  25 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  26 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  27 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  28 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  29 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  30 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  31 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  32 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  33 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  34 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  35 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  36 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  37 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  38 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  39 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  40 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  41 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  42 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  43 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  44 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  45 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  46 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  47 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  48 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  49 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  50 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  51 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  52 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  53 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  54 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  55 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  56 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  57 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  58 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  59 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  60 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  61 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  62 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  63 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  64 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  65 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  66 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  67 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  68 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  69 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  70 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  71 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  72 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  73 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  74 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  75 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  76 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  77 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  78 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  79 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  80 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  81 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  82 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  83 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  84 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  85 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  86 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  87 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  88 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  89 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  90 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  91 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  92 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  93 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  94 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  95 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  96 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  97 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  98 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  99 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  100 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  101 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  102 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  103 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  104 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  105 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  106 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  107 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  108 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  109 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  110 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  111 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  112 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  113 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  114 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  115 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  116 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  117 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  118 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  119 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  120 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  121 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  122 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  123 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  124 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  125 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  126 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  127 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  128 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  129 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  130 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  131 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  132 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  133 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  134 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  135 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  136 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  137 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  138 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  139 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  140 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  141 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  142 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  143 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  144 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  145 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  146 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  147 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  148 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  149 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  150 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  151 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  152 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  153 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  154 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  155 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  156 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  157 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  158 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  159 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  160 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  161 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  162 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  163 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  164 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  165 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  166 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  167 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  168 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  169 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  170 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  171 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  172 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  173 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  174 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  175 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  176 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  177 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  178 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  179 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  180 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  181 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  182 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  183 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  184 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  185 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  186 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  187 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  188 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  189 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  190 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  191 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  192 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  193 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  194 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  195 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  196 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  197 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  198 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  199 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
  200 0xf751dbee __clone+0x5d() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0xf77fa440 __kernel_vsyscall+0x10 in [vdso].so: popl    %ebp
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (167 modules)
PE    400000-  416000   Deferred        lolclient
PE  10000000-114fb000   Export          adobe air
PE  19cb0000-1a160000   Deferred        webkit
ELF 7b800000-7ba5f000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba5f000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bce1000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bce1000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf03000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7c4ad000-7c4f1000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7c4b0000-7c4f1000   \               usp10
ELF 7c542000-7c55e000   Deferred        jsproxy<elf>
  \-PE  7c550000-7c55e000   \               jsproxy
ELF 7c55e000-7c59a000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  7c560000-7c59a000   \               winhttp
ELF 7c59a000-7c5dc000   Deferred        rsaenh<elf>
  \-PE  7c5a0000-7c5dc000   \               rsaenh
ELF 7c620000-7c63d000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7c646000-7c660000   Deferred        cryptnet<elf>
  \-PE  7c650000-7c660000   \               cryptnet
ELF 7c660000-7c77b000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7c680000-7c77b000   \               opengl32
ELF 7c77b000-7c8c3000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7c790000-7c8c3000   \               wined3d
ELF 7c8c3000-7c900000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7c8d0000-7c900000   \               d3d9
ELF 7cb02000-7cb2e000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF 7cb2e000-7cca6000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF 7cca6000-7ccda000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF 7ccda000-7cd4c000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF 7cd4c000-7cdbb000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-4.0.so
ELF 7cdbb000-7ce0a000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF 7ce0a000-7cf00000   Deferred        libasound.so.2
ELF 7d00a000-7d013000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF 7d013000-7d01a000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF 7d01a000-7d024000   Deferred        libwrap.so.0
ELF 7d024000-7d02b000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF 7d02b000-7d032000   Deferred        libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so
ELF 7d110000-7d140000   Deferred        winealsa<elf>
  \-PE  7d120000-7d140000   \               winealsa
ELF 7d140000-7d162000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d150000-7d162000   \               mmdevapi
ELF 7d162000-7d177000   Deferred        schannel<elf>
  \-PE  7d170000-7d177000   \               schannel
ELF 7d177000-7d19b000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d180000-7d19b000   \               imm32
ELF 7d19b000-7d1c3000   Deferred        mlang<elf>
  \-PE  7d1a0000-7d1c3000   \               mlang
ELF 7d209000-7d21c000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d210000-7d21c000   \               psapi
ELF 7d21c000-7d283000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  7d220000-7d283000   \               dbghelp
ELF 7d283000-7d297000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7d297000-7d2c7000   Deferred        p11-kit-trust.so
ELF 7d2c7000-7d2ce000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7d2ce000-7d2d3000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7d2d3000-7d31e000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7d31e000-7d35a000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d35a000-7d3e0000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 7d3e0000-7d3f2000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
ELF 7d3f2000-7d3fe000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7d3fe000-7d42e000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7d42e000-7d4ec000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7d4ec000-7d4fe000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7d4fe000-7d50c000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7d50c000-7d5d5000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 7d5d5000-7d61a000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d61a000-7d687000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7d689000-7d694000   Deferred        libjson-c.so.2
ELF 7d697000-7d6aa000   Deferred        gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so
ELF 7d6aa000-7d6c5000   Deferred        dinput8<elf>
  \-PE  7d6b0000-7d6c5000   \               dinput8
ELF 7d6c5000-7d70d000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7d6d0000-7d70d000   \               dsound
ELF 7d70d000-7d725000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7d725000-7d729000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7d729000-7d748000   Deferred        dnsapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d730000-7d748000   \               dnsapi
ELF 7d748000-7d76d000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d750000-7d76d000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7d76d000-7d79b000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7d770000-7d79b000   \               netapi32
ELF 7d79b000-7d7cd000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7d7a0000-7d7cd000   \               secur32
ELF 7d7cd000-7d81a000   Deferred        liblcms2.so.2
ELF 7d81a000-7d83a000   Deferred        mscms<elf>
  \-PE  7d820000-7d83a000   \               mscms
ELF 7d83a000-7d87c000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7d840000-7d87c000   \               winspool
ELF 7d87c000-7d968000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7d880000-7d968000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7d968000-7d9a7000   Deferred        oleacc<elf>
  \-PE  7d970000-7d9a7000   \               oleacc
ELF 7d9a7000-7d9d1000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d9b0000-7d9d1000   \               msacm32
ELF 7d9d1000-7da89000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7d9e0000-7da89000   \               winmm
ELF 7da89000-7db5a000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7da90000-7db5a000   \               crypt32
ELF 7db5a000-7db91000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7db60000-7db91000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7dbc0000-7dbf6000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7dbd0000-7dbf6000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7dbf6000-7dbfc000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7dbfc000-7dc07000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7dc07000-7dc17000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7dc17000-7dc1b000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7dc1b000-7dc26000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7dc26000-7dc31000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7dc31000-7dc37000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7dc37000-7dc3b000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7dc3b000-7dc42000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7dc42000-7dc46000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7dc46000-7dc68000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7dc68000-7dd9c000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7dd9c000-7ddaf000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7ddb1000-7ddb6000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7ddb6000-7ddc9000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7ddc0000-7ddc9000   \               msimg32
ELF 7ddd2000-7de65000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7dde0000-7de65000   \               winex11
ELF 7deaa000-7ded3000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7ded3000-7df0e000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7df0e000-7df36000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7df36000-7dfd6000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7dff9000-7e019000   Deferred        cabinet<elf>
  \-PE  7e000000-7e019000   \               cabinet
ELF 7e019000-7e121000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e020000-7e121000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e121000-7e148000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7e130000-7e148000   \               mpr
ELF 7e148000-7e161000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e161000-7e1de000   Dwarf           wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7e170000-7e1de000   \               wininet
ELF 7e1de000-7e320000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e200000-7e320000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e320000-7e3a5000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e330000-7e3a5000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e3a5000-7e4e7000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e3c0000-7e4e7000   \               ole32
ELF 7e4e7000-7e58b000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  7e4f0000-7e58b000   \               urlmon
ELF 7e58b000-7e68a000   Deferred        msi<elf>
  \-PE  7e5a0000-7e68a000   \               msi
ELF 7e68a000-7e6fa000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e6a0000-7e6fa000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e6fa000-7e819000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e710000-7e819000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e819000-7e976000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e830000-7e976000   \               user32
ELF 7e976000-7e9f0000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e980000-7e9f0000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e9f0000-7ec27000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea00000-7ec27000   \               shell32
ELF 7ec27000-7ec34000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ec34000-7ec40000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ec40000-7ec59000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ec59000-7ec62000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7efd4000-7efdd000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7efe7000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f73e7000-f742d000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF f742d000-f7432000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7432000-f75e0000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f75e0000-f75fc000   Dwarf           libpthread.so.0
ELF f7620000-f77d6000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f77d8000-f77fa000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77fa000-f77fb000   Dwarf           [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000001d    0
    0000001c    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001b    0
    00000018    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
00000019 plugplay.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001a    0
00000020 rads_user_kernel.exe
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000021    0
00000023 explorer.exe
    00000024    0
0000002f LoLLauncher.exe
    00000031    0
    00000030    0
00000033 LoLPatcher.exe
    000000d0    0
    000000cf    0
    000000aa    0
    000000a9    0
    000000a8    0
    000000a7    0
    00000044    0
    00000043    0
    00000042    0
    0000003e    0
    0000003c    0
    0000003b    0
    0000003a    0
    00000039    0
    00000038    0
    00000037    0
    00000036    0
    00000035    0
    00000034    0
000000ab (D) C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\RADS\projects\lol_air_client\releases\0.0.1.162\deploy\LolClient.exe
    00000063    0 <==
    00000064    0
    000000d7    0
    000000dc    0
    000000d1    0
    00000069    0
    00000067    0
    00000066    0
    00000061    0
    000000df    2
    000000de    0
    000000b7    0
    000000b6    0
    000000b5    0
    000000b4    0
    000000b3    0
    000000b2    0
    000000b1    0
    000000b0    0
    000000af    0
    000000ae    0
    000000ad    0
    000000ac    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.7.24
    Platform: i386
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.13.0-65-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

https://www.playonlinux.com/ru/app-1135-League_Of_Legends.html

"Wine's wininet is being passed an URL longer than its internal limit 
you can clone wine source code, change INTERNET_MAX_PATH_LENGTH in include/wininet.h to 4096, compile wine and replace ~/.PlayOnLinux/wine/linux-x86/$LOLWINEVERSION/lib/wine/wininet.dll.so with dlls/wininet/wininet.dll.so. Remember to make backup of a file!"